# IntelliJ Idea 11 - No menu to generate Java code from WSDL

Tags: intellij-idea, wsdl2java

Despite I enabled Web services support, I can not see "**Generate Java code from WSDL**" menu item in **Tools -> WebServices**.
Do I need to install any plugin or something else for this?

Comment: Does it help if you select the `.wsdl` file in a project first?

Comment: Works for me from the [context menu](http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/1382/20121120172755.png).

Comment: Where can I find this option in year 2022 and using version 2021.3.1 (Ultimate)? Thanks and Happy New Year :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html

Useful tutorial here
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_a_simple_JaxWS_WebService

Hope this helps.